# How to use properly ConfigurationManager.GetSection() in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, .net-core

I am having some problems for getting the configuration values using this method in my web application in .net core.

```
 var settings =  ConfigurationManager.GetSection("JwtBearerSettings/Issuer");
```

This method is called by one project I am referencing. It is also in .NET Core 2.2 and the config settings are on the file

> appsettings.json

The thing is that when I am debugging always I get `settings == null` I have been looking for similar questions but I couldn't solve this.

My json is

```
{
     "JwtBearerSettings": {
        "Issuer": "Auth.MyStuff.Api",
        "PrivateKey": "Blablabla",
        "ExpirationTime": "15"
        }
}
```

Do you know if is even possible to use this method?

Am I missing something between, for getting the web app configuration with my library?

Comment: The section separator is `:`, not `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to read config out is to simply read out a value at a time. Structured data is separated by colons, so your example becomes:

```
var issuer = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"];
```

This is clearly a pain if you are reading a lot of settings. So you can instead simply Bind a model object to a section. For example, if you had a model object with properties in it, say

```
class JwtBearerSettings {
    public string Issuer {get;set;}
}
```

then you can use `GetSection` to bind to a settings object:

```
var jbs = new JwtBearerSettings();
Configuration.GetSection("JwtBearerSettings").Bind(jbs);
```

This pattern is used by a lot of libraries as it lets you provide as little, or as much config as you need - as long as the model is pre-filled with sensible defaults.

The third pattern supported .Net Core can be used with DI:

Here you can register your configuration model with the service factory:

```
var jbs = Configuration.GetSection("JwtBearerSettings");
services.Configure<JwtBearerSettings>(jbs);
```

and, to reference your settings in a service, simply add IOptions as a ctor parameter:

```
public MyService(IOptions<JwtBearerSettings> jwtOptions)
{
    Config = jwtOptions.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you've created a property like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
}
```

You can then access the elements, like this:

```
var issuer = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"],
```